# Hyperledger Fabric altering fabcar example

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I've been working through the fabcar example and have it running it perfectly when no alterations have happened.  What I'm trying to do is update the fabcar.go code to add more fields and simply play around w/ the example, however my docker images aren't updating w/ the correct code.

To install the chaincode, this command is run on the cli container:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0 -p github.com/fabcar
```

The cli container has set this volume:

```
./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
```

however, after code/go updates (I've actually changed it from Car to a Ticket object with entirely new fields and updated all relevant chain commands to reflect), [teardown](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/basic-network/teardown.sh), then start up again I still am seeing all the old fields.

What am I missing here?

Here's a snippet of the code changing to tickets on the "Invoke" function

```
func (s *SmartContract) Invoke(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {

    // Retrieve the requested Smart Contract function and arguments
    function, args := APIstub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    // Route to the appropriate handler function to interact with the ledger appropriately
    if function == "queryTicket" {
        return s.queryTicket(APIstub, args)
    } else if function == "initLedger" {
        return s.initLedger(APIstub)
    } else if function == "createTicket" {
        return s.createTicket(APIstub, args)
    } else if function == "queryAllTickets" {
        return s.queryAllTickets(APIstub)
    } else if function == "sellTicket" {
        return s.sellTicket(APIstub, args)
    }

    return shim.Error("Invalid Smart Contract function name.")
}
```

But doing this I simply receive the message "Invalid Smart Contract function name." when calling w/ the following:

```
const request = {
    chaincodeId: options.chaincode_id,
    txId: transaction_id,
    fcn: 'queryAllTickets',
    args: ['']
};
```

Comment: When you say "teardown, then start up again", what do you mean?

Comment: teardown meaning bring down the docker images using basic-network/teardown.sh which just "downs" all the containers.  start meaning just calling the start.sh bash script that brings the containers back up, after I've made the changes.

Comment: Have you modified the rest of the contract, the places where the function "QuesryAllTickets" was defined?

Comment: yeah, it's all edited and doesn't have any code for cars anymore, i'm just simply switching it over to refer to tickets as the asset

Comment: @farhan3 The [teardown](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/basic-network/teardown.sh) is the file which mainly shuts down all the containers.

Comment: @ChrisFricke can you go into the container (`docker exec -it cli bash`) and verify that the new code has been mounted under `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/`

Comment: @farhan3, verified.  The new code is there!  That's a relief at least :).  Now I'm very confused as to why the container isn't responding w/ the updated ledger json entries.

Comment: @farhan3 That may not be a problem, because [start.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/basic-network/start.sh) is properly mounting all the codes using the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/basic-network/docker-compose.yml#L107)

Comment: When running startFabric.sh, it runs "initLedger" but the response is for cars not tickets, so somehow the old code is running somewhere even though we have the correct code in the docker container

Comment: @Ayushya I just wanted to verify his changes were in the correct place. Chris can you try bumping the chaincode version or changing the chaincode id during your chaincode install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest two possible approaches:

1. Install chaincode with new name or incremented version

Same name, but updated version:

```
peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 2.0 -p github.com/fabcar
```

or same version, but new name:

```
peer chaincode install -n tickets -v 1.0 -p github.com/fabcar
```

2. Cleanup old chaincode container and install updated version of alternated chaincode over again.

You can use following command to remove old chaincode container image:

```
docker images | grep fabcar | awk '{print $2}' | docker rmi
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. Since he wasn't incrementing the version or changing the id, fabric was still using the old chaincode image.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared that up.  I was just killing the containers not removing images.  Great help!