# Hyperledger Fabric fabcar example chaincode in dev mode (peer-chaincodedev)

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to alter the fabcar example from fabric samples to be able to quickly iterate over the chaincode development. Per default, I'd always need to remove the image and re-run the setup script, as [this question elaborated on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575813/hyperledger-fabric-altering-fabcar-example). This takes ~30s.

I saw the flag `--peer-chaincodedev=true` in the docker-compose and wonder how I can get that to work.

I followed the [Tutorial "Chaincode for Developers"](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html) and compared this with the docker-compose of the basic-network. I noticed there is a container named `chaincode` which runs an image named `fabric-ccenv`. I added this definition to the docker compose but can't instantiate the chaincode on the peer. How is this supposed to be done?

I'm trying to run

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

in the cli but I'm getting

```
2017-08-14 11:54:13.404 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-14 11:54:13.404 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-14 11:54:13.406 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2017-08-14 11:54:13.406 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2017-08-14 11:54:13.407 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: plaintext: 0A95070A6708031A0C08E59EC6CC0510...324D53500A04657363630A0476736363
2017-08-14 11:54:13.407 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: digest: 61C75870AB68C1E7D6921DB4CA6029A0093A3D57DB421BC697864555BFC81167
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--peer-chaincodedev=true` or so called dev mode is introduced to allow short circuit while developing a chaincode, namely to allow you skip the official process of packaging, compilation and deployment of docker image with chaincode. Instead you can execute your chaincode from your IDE and debug and work interactively with it. For example you might have some very simple chaincode:

```
type smartContract struct {
}

func (p *smartContract) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (p *smartContract) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    actionName, params := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

    if actionName == "hello" {
         shim.putState("Greeting", "Hello World")
         return shim.Success(nil)
    }
return shim.Error(errors.New("Undefined function"))
}

func main() {
    err := shim.Start(new(smartContract))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting chaincode: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Now if you running your peer with `--peer-chaincodedev=true` flag you can execute your chaincode from its folder e.g.:

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=chaincodeName:v1.0 go run smartContract.go
```

Next one you have it running, you need to install and instantiate the chaincode in the channel as usual. Of course you can run chaincode from IDE of your choice.

**NOTE**: while instantiating the chaincode you need to use name and version you've defined in `CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=chaincodeName:v1.0` variable. And of course you need to have a channel created.

```
# Creating and joining the channel
peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel -f mychannel.tx
peer channel join -o localhost:7050 --blockpath mychannel.block

# Once chaincode is running we can install and instantiate it
peer chaincode install -o localhost:7050 -n chaincodeName -v 1.0 -p github.com/somepackage/chaincode
peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -n chaincodeName -v 1.0 -C mychannel -c '{"Args": ["init"]}'
```

---

Back to your problem, I think the error you see might be because of misconfiguration of your MSP or you have not created a channel. In case of wrong configuration, you need to make sure that `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` environmental variable points to valid location, for instance as used in many examples in context of cli container:

```
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
```

Also to specify MSP ID:

```
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
```

And address of endorsing peer:

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Artem, I now found the solution to my problem.

I copied the docker-compose definition for the `chaincode` container, which in turn overwrote the mounted volumes. So whenever this was mounted, the MSP could not be found. So I removed the `chaincode` container again.

I moved the `install`, `instantiate` and `invoke` commands from the `startFabric.sh` script into an `install.sh` script. I start the docker containers by executing `./startFabric.sh`. Then I compile and run the chaincode on the host with

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=fabcar:${VERSION} go run fabcar.go
```

Now I need to execute `install.sh` with the version used in the previous step.

After I make changes to the chaincode, I will recompile the chaincode on the host, incrementing the version. Then I execute `upgrade.sh`, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Exit on first error
set -e

if [ -z "$1" ]; then echo "Error: Needs chaincode version"; exit; fi
CHAINCODE_VERSION=$1

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v ${CHAINCODE_VERSION} -p github.com/fabcar
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -v ${CHAINCODE_VERSION} -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```