# chaincode error (status: 500, message: Invalid Smart Contract function name

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts

I'm trying to create an app on top of  Hyperledger fabric.  I have written smart contract in GO and trying to invoke it using nodejs script.   But getting below error.

I'm following this tutorial : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html#

```
node invoke.js
Store path:/home/vagrant/hyperledger/kyc-hyperledger/kyc-app/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
Assigning transaction_id:  bbad72223a50793f012bd76bd902a816807bde759e639dc6805db70aec41df4e
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Invalid Smart Contract function name.)
    at new createStatusError (/home/vagrant/hyperledger/kyc-hyperledger/kyc-app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/vagrant/hyperledger/kyc-hyperledger/kyc-app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
Transaction proposal was bad
Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...
Failed to invoke successfully :: Error: Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...
```

Error log from peer:

```
2018-05-16 15:52:31.399 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 03f [kyc-channel][bbad7222] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"kyc"  response status 500 for txid: bbad72223a50793f012bd76bd902a816807bde759e639dc6805db70aec41df4e
```

Request from invoke.js

```
var request = {
    //targets: let default to the peer assigned to the client
    chaincodeId: 'kyc',
    fcn: 'updateUser',
    args: ['USER1','bengaluru'],
    chainId: 'kyc-channel',
    txId: tx_id
};
```

Invoke function of smart contract:

```
    if function == "queryUser" {
        return s.queryUser(APIstub, args)
    } else if function == "initLedger" {
        return s.initLedger(APIstub)
    }else if function == "updateUser" {
        return s.updateUser(APIstub, args)
    }
    return shim.Error("Please provide valid SmartContract name")
}
```

can anyone help as why it showing Invalid Smart Contract function name.?
I'm able to invoke queryUser and initLedger functions succesfully.

getting below error when i tried to execute  chaincode directly from cli-container.

```
vagrant@fabric:~/hyperledger/kyc-hyperledger/kyc-app$ docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.abc.com/users/Admin@org1.abc.com/msp" cli peer chaincode query -C kyc-channel -n kyc -c '{"Args":["updateUser","USER1","bengaluru"]}'
2018-05-16 16:09:56.488 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-05-16 16:09:56.488 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-16 16:09:56.489 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-05-16 16:09:56.489 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-05-16 16:09:56.489 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-05-16 16:09:56.489 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0A9C070A6808031A0C08D4AFF1D70510...55534552310A0962656E67616C757275
2018-05-16 16:09:56.489 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 883983F39536F25CBD155CC2493328839EF5406F717A1B7F1632EE3515DE29EA
Error: Error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Invalid Smart Contract function name.) - <nil>
Usage:
  peer chaincode query [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string   The channel on which this command should be executed
  -c, --ctor string        Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -x, --hex                If true, output the query value byte array in hexadecimal. Incompatible with --raw
  -n, --name string        Name of the chaincode
  -r, --raw                If true, output the query value as raw bytes, otherwise format as a printable string
  -t, --tid string         Name of a custom ID generation algorithm (hashing and decoding) e.g. sha256base64

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --transient string                    Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

But initLedger function works fine from cli.

```
  vagrant@fabric:~$ docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.abc.com/users/Admin@org1.abc.com/msp" cli peer chaincode query -C kyc-channel -n kyc -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}'
2018-05-16 16:31:06.974 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-05-16 16:31:06.974 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-16 16:31:06.974 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-05-16 16:31:06.974 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-05-16 16:31:06.974 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-05-16 16:31:06.975 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0A9C070A6808031A0C08CAB9F1D70510...79631A0C0A0A696E69744C6564676572
2018-05-16 16:31:06.975 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 36456570541FBB5AD1BBAC6F4B732398D7600FEE43BBD792E028BC6C8095F0E0
Query Result:
2018-05-16 16:31:06.982 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved.

fabric was using old chaincode docker image.
I had to removed chaincode docker image which was previously generated. which didn't had updateUser function.

Another approach is to update version or change name of chaincode.

:for information refer this answer.
[Hyperledger Fabric altering fabcar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575813/hyperledger-fabric-altering-fabcar-example)